# How associativity holds on set of all bijective functions on a finite set?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I came across following statement:

> The set of all bijective functions on a finite set forms a group under function composition.

The proof was given as follows:

> We can have identity function as $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)\}$.
>   Since function is bijective and mapping to same set, we can have an inverse for any function by inverting the relation (changing the mapping $a\rightarrow b$ to $b\rightarrow a$).
>   Since the function maps to the same set, it must be closed and associative also.

I was thinking is associativity really holds in above set. For example, consider the finite set: $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and two bijective functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ as follows:
[image]

Now, $f_1(f_2(1))=f_1(3)=3$ and $f_2(f_1(1))=f_2(2)=1$.
So, I feel its not bijective. Am I incorrectly evaluating associativity?

Comment: Composition of functions is always associative, even for non-bijective ones.

Comment: You have checked commutativity, not associativity. Indeed, the group of bijections on a set need not be (and almost never is) commutative.

Comment: It looks like you have confused associativity for commutativity.

Comment: ok I guess I am not able to guess how to evaluate composition. Usually we check if $(a*b)*c = a*(b*c)$. But here $*$ is binary operator, whereas $f_x$ are unary (Am I sounding stupid with this statement?). How can I evaluate associativity for unary operator?

Comment: What you proved is that $f_1 \circ f_2 \neq f_2\circ f_1$. To verify associativity, you need to take any functions $f_k$ for $k=1,2,3$ and check that $f_1 \circ (f_2 \circ f_3) = (f_1 \circ f_2)\circ f_3$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde want to give one more +1 for "even for non-bijective ones"

Comment: Incidentally, I think historically things went just the other way around: the "four properties" of abstract groups were patterned just upon the four properties holding for the bijections on a (not necessarily finite) set under composition, namely: closure, associativity, unit, inverse elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example shows that compostion is not commutative. It has nothing to do with being associative.

Comment: ok I guess I am not able to guess how to evaluate composition. Usually we check if $(a*b)*c = a*(b*c)$. But here $*$ is binary operator, whereas $f_x$ are unary (Am I sounding stupid with this statement?). How can I evaluate associativity for unary operator?

Comment: Associativity, in this context, means that $f_1\circ(f_2\circ f_3)=(f_1\circ f_2)\circ f_3$. This is always true, even if the functions are not bijective.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume $f_1(a) = b$ and $f_2(b) = c$ and $f_3(c)= d$ then

$f_2\circ f_1(a) = f_2(f_1(a)) =f_2(b) =c$.

And $f_3\circ f_2(b) = f_3(f_2(b)) =f_3(c)=d$.

And so

$f_3\circ (f_2\circ f_1)(a) = f_3(f_2\circ f_1(a))=f_3(c) =d$

and $(f_3\circ f_2)\circ f_1(a) = f_3\circ f_2(f_1(a)) =f_3\circ f_2(b) = d =f_3\circ (f_2\circ f_1)(a)$

So associativity holds.